# Transition on class removal not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to get a container to come down when i click on an item in my menu. The animation downwards works fine. But the moment i click a different item in my menu, it doesnt animate upwards.

Css:

```
.card{
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    transform: translateY(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
    height:0;
    min-height: 0;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.275);
    transition-property: opacity,transform;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
.card-appeared{
    margin-top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    min-height: 300px;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    height:auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="aboutme" class="container card ">
    About me
</div>
<div id="gallery" class="container card card-appeared">
    Gallery
</div>
```

Basic javascript for adding and removing classes

```
function appear(child){
    parent.classList.remove("card-appeared");
    let others = document.getElementsByClassName("card-appeared");
    for(var i = 0; i < others.length;i++){
        others[i].classList.remove("card-appeared");
    }
    child.classList.add("card-appeared");
}
function dissapear(child) {
    child.classList.remove("card-appeared");
    parent.classList.add("card-appeared");
}
```

`others` is the list of other cards in the page and the parent is the very first container.

If you need any other code, please let me know. I cannot seem to get the upwards animation working but the animation down does work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an explicit height is only specified when the class `card-appeared` is added, with the property `min-height`, the expected behaviour cannot be observed when this class is removed again, since the inherit state of the element in question has no explicit height defined. So it just "pops" back up.

To resolve this, consider the below:

```
.card {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  transform: translateY(-600px); /* adjusted */
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  min-height: 300px; /* added */
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.175, .885, .32, 1.275);
  transition-property: opacity, transform;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.card-appeared {
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-300px); /* adjusted */
  transition-delay: 1s;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Breakdown:** Since static positioning is being used here, elements with y-positioning offsets will still occupy space in the DOM. In order to account for this, the values of the `transform: translateY()` properties must be adjusted accordingly now that the elements in question always have a minimum height defined.

**For Consideration:** A better solution to this may be utilizing `absolute` positioning; this will remove the elements in question from the *natural flow of the document*, meaning you will not have to account for space occupied in the DOM by these elements, so `transform: translateY()` property values can remain intuitive.

Comment: Thank you for the brief explanation. Tho the solution given in code doesnt really work the way it should (Appears half off screen on first container). The absolute position trick does work. Sadly im not a fan of absolute positioning due to document flow but ill use it in this case!

Comment: @Ellisan `absolute` positioning is ideal for situations where you have off-canvas content that is required to appear under dynamic circumstances. So don't hesitate to use `absolute` positioning when it's necessary - if you feed it, look after it well, and remember to take it for walks - it'll do right by you ;)

Comment: @Ellisan Regarding the initial solution, you may find that you need to adjust `transform: translateY()` property values to suit the requirements of your specific environment - the above demonstration was tested with the code provided in the question and worked suitably - although I understand that there could be further code in your production that I could not account for while testing this solution.